# install angular-cli, debian, digitalocean

Tags: angularjs, angular-cli

```
rtoews@toewsweb-deb:/var/www/lab.toewsweb.net$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.5 (jessie)
Release:        8.5
Codename:       jessie
rtoews@toewsweb-deb:/var/www/lab.toewsweb.net$ npm cache clear
rtoews@toewsweb-deb:/var/www/lab.toewsweb.net$ sudo npm install -g angular-cli
[sudo] password for rtoews:
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
rtoews@toewsweb-deb:/var/www/lab.toewsweb.net$ npm list -g --depth=0807
/usr/lib
├── babel@6.5.2
├── http-server@0.9.0
├── karma@1.4.0
├── npm@4.1.1
└── webpack@1.13.3

rtoews@toewsweb-deb:/var/www/lab.toewsweb.net$ ng -h
-bash: /usr/bin/ng: No such file or directory
```

I'm trying to install angular-cli on a digitalocean account running Debian 8.5. The instructions are as simple as they are ubiquitous. I issue the sudo npm install -g angular-cli command, and I'm eventually returned to a prompt, with no indication of a terminal error.

However, if I then do an npm list -g --depth=0 to see what's installed, angular-cli is missing. Should it be?

More importantly, the ng command doesn't appear to be available.

Suggestions?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/503

Comment: My issue is related to /issues/503 (ng command not found); however, I judged it to be distinct, as my npm list -g --depth=0 indicates that angular-cli wasn't installed in the first place, immediately after I executed the npm install command.